# I am on Codecademy Make an interactive website, I can't pass 7/9 "Disable the button 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

When l submit the code, it keeps telling me:

> make sure you have defined all the variables!

```
var main = function() {

$('.btn').click(function() {
var post = $('.status-box').val();
$('').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
$('.status-box').val('');
$('.counter').text('140');
});
$('.status-box').keyup(function() {
var postLength = $(this).val().length;
var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
$('.counter').text(charactersLeft);
if(charactersLeft < 0) {
$('.btn').addClass('disabled');
}
else if(characterLeft == 140) {
$('.btn').addClass('disabled');
}
else { 
 $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
}
});
$('.btn').addClass('disabled');
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Does codeadacedemy not suggest using code formatting/indent to make code readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if(characterLeft == 140) {
```

Your variable is called `charactersLeft`.